# How to release ViewController after pushviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimageview

I have 2 view, named viewcontroller1,viewcontroller2. every viewcontroller has load about 3 pictures(load it in XIB) , when i try to use [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller], to push view1 to view2, the memory cannt  release.(i want to konw it cannt release viewcontrller1 or cannt release uiimageview)any error for my code ??

viewcontroller1 code just like this:

viewcontroller1.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImageView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *topwallImageView;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonImageView;
```

viewcontroller1.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
self.mainImageView = nil;
self.topwallImageView = nil;
self.buttonImageView = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

-(void)dealloc
{
[mainImageView release];
[topwallImageView   release];
[buttonImageView release];
[super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)main2ViewController:(id)sender
{
Main2ViewController *main2ViewController =[[Main2ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Main2ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:main2ViewController animated:NO];
[main2ViewController release];
}
```

Comment: The problem might be in loading the other view controller also. or does it actually crash on the line where you release ur second viewcontroller? did you apply breakpoints to track where its actually crashing?

Comment: @Apple_iOS0304 my question is not crashing. is cannt not release viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You have to study more detailed about **Object Communication and Memory management** in iOS.

Also please try to use ARC. **Automatic reference counting** (ARC) was introduced in the iOS 5 sdk to free Objective-C programmers from having to handle memory management by making memory management the job of the compiler.

You can **convert your project to ARC enabled** using [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)

You can't release **viewcontroller1** and its IBOutlet properties while viewcontroller2  is visible or after pushed **viewcontroller2**. Because you pushed **viewcontroller2** from viewcontroller1.**viewcontroller1** is the container/parent of viewcontroller2. **viewcontroller2 will not exist with out viewcontroller1**

About the IBOutlet imageview images, you can set it to nil .Eg: **yourImageview.image = nil;** However it will not release the IBOoutlet Imageview memory.

IBOutlet imageview will get released when a release method called to viewcontroller1 because you released it properly in viewcontroller1 dealloc method :)

About your **Main2ViewController** method:You handled memory properly in your code

When you call the pushViewController , it will retain the controller which is pushed by default. note that your are not the owner. It will release automatically when the controller is popped out.However you have to release the allocated Main2ViewController. So your code is fine :)

Comment: Thanks Ramshad, what is mean by "not release the resources"??That mean if i want to release uiiamgeview.image i have wirte it on .m file ??? (like this : uiimageview.imageview = [uiimage imageconterfilepath:1.png]) after i pushviewcontroller view1 release or not release ? can i release the uiimageview on viewcontroller2 ?? BTW how to popup viewcontroller ?

Comment: I have already try you code "youImageview.image=nil" i doesnt work. BTW can i use toolbar controller to replace navigationcontroller ?

Comment: youImageview.image=nil will not release the IBOoutlet memory.